# Spring MVC custom URL

Tags: spring-mvc

I'd like to customize the URL of a current web application. For example the current default landing page is

```
https://somedomain/index
```

Now I need to customize the URL based on the user company. For example if the company is ABC then the URL would be

```
https://abc.somedomain/index
```

**OR**

```
https://somedomain/abc/index
```

And for this company I want to apply a custom CSS`

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: How many such subdomain will you have?

Comment: Can I have it like a lot ? Maybe few thousands. Is there such setting can map any subdomains to a fix IP ? Then in the web app I tried to apply css based on the `subdomain` name.

Comment: And you will also have thousands of css files?

Comment: Yes. I need to provide a customized CSS for each company. Any better suggestion ?

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well what I'm writing here is not the best solution. But, I think it will satisfy what you are trying to do.

My strong suggestion is to find a better way of doing this.

```
<c:set var="serverName" value="${ pageContext.request.serverName }"></c:set>
<c:set var="split" value="${ fn:split(serverName, '.') }"></c:set>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/${split[0]}.index.css">
```

this should get compile to

if http://abc.domain.com/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/abc.index.css">
```

if http://xyz.domain.com/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/xyz.index.css">
```

Comment: Thanks. By the way, do I have to manually create the subdomains too ? Can I map something like `*.subdomain` to a fix IP ?

Comment: Yes, you can. I've tried it in godaddy. I'm sure others will let you do the same too.